# How to get data from an API of the same origin?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have a route (/user/{id}) that returns user information in json format. I want to display some user info on my index(/) page. So, in my handler for the index(/), I have

```
const host ="https//www.example.com"
const url = host + "/user/1"
const response = await fetch(url, init)
```

But, the thing is that it hangs and times out. I guess it is because, it is still serving the request for the index page, which is also making another request to /user/{id}. So, the second request doesn't seem to be served as the handler is occupied by the first request in my opinion.
Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: There's no problem with making concurrent requests. Your quoted code contains a typo -- you are missing a `:` after `https`. Is that problem present in your original code? If that's no it, then you will need to provide more details here...

Comment: Oh, are you trying to have the Worker make a request to itself? Workers cannot make requests that loop back to themselves. Instead you need to structure your code so that it calls the function you want directly.